# How to ask Jenkins detect restricted words in source code and fail build?

Tags: php, git, jenkins, grep, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins CI.

Source code is PHP.

Jenkins grabs every 5 minutes source code from GIT.

How to configure to scan source code for resticted words:

- sqlsrv_
- mssql_

I need it to monitor another developers to avoid using deprecated functions in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you define Sniffs (Custom based sniffs) and those can grab The mentioned words whenever they appear. You can then make your build fail or display error message accordingly.

I have been able to create my own Sniffs after seeing how Sniffs are developed in:

https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a static code analysis tool for PHP. Then you need to configure Jenkins to launch that tool.

There are tons available.

Here is a question listing many static code analysis tools for PHP:
**[Is there a static code analyzer [like Lint] for PHP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)**

Here is a question about linking one of those (PHP Code Sniffer) with Jenkins:
**[Using Jenkins and Php Code Sniffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673963/using-jenkins-and-php-code-sniffer)**