# Is there some way to integerate cruisecontrol and jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, cruisecontrol.net, phpcodesniffer

I require php extension of cruisecontrol which I want to use for code quality analysis upon jenkins build.

How can I achieve this?

If in case this cannot be achieved then what can be other possible way by which I can carry code quality analysis compatible to cruisecontrol on my jenkins build (analysis that includes codesniffer, pmd, psr-1, psr-2).

Answer (score 0):

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674977/6309), you can use phpcs (code sniffer).

See [jenkins-php.org](http://jenkins-php.org/automation.html) for a complete list of php ant task.
Those ant tasks can be run within a maven `pom.xml` [as seen in this example](https://gist.github.com/kathiedart/2414936), using the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/c).

The idea remain: if you can script it or integrate it to maven, and run it from command line, then it is trivial to make the same call from a Jenkins job.
Test the script or ant or maven call of those php analysis tools locally first.
Then create a Jenkins job.